# python Is it possible to format string in the cell via pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file and the example of the data row are as follows:

```
Col A    Col B    Col C
‘Cat’     ‘9’     ‘’
‘Dog’     ‘’     ‘male’
Expected result -> 
Cat 9
Dog  male
```

I have used replace(“ ‘ “, “ “, regex=True) but the ‘ ‘ are not disappeared.

Comment: What is `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: The print that I used is print(df.head())

Comment: Do you need `df = df.replace("[‘’]","", regex=True)` or `df = df.replace("'","", regex=True)` ?

Comment: try using `df.replace("[‘’]", "",regex=True)`

Comment: My stupid mistake... thank you guys, it’s working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace`:

```
df = df.replace("[‘’]","", regex=True)
print (df)
  Col A Col B Col C
0   Cat     9      
1   Dog        male
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, just based on looking at what you pasted, that your values are not `''` but Unicode characters. @jezrael alludes to this in their comment. Thus, replacing based on the ascii `'` doesn't catch the Unicode.

One possible way to check this is to do:

`import unidecode
(df.applymap(unidecode.unidecode)
    .apply(lambda s: s.str.replace("'", "")
)`

This does two things:

1. Escapes Unicode to ascii using the [`unidecode`](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) library, which is a pretty convenient all-purposes library for stripping Unicode characters to pretty sensible ascii equivalents. If you do text-processing and string normalization a lot, that can really help.
2. Uses Pandas' [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) library which is an amazing extension. If you do EDA over string data on a regular basis like I do, this will literally change your life. I was in the dark for years before I met this library. (Another great pandas gem is the `dt` library.)